# Inline CSS for Safari only

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I've used `roboto` font from Google Fonts, but in Safari `font-weight:bold` doesn't work and I don't want to use css class.

Is there any hack for inline css only for Safari?

```
body{
     font-family:'roboto';
   }



<label style="font-weight:bold"></label>
```

Comment: it's `label` not `lable`

Comment: http://www.maketecheasier.com/use-google-roboto-font-everywhere/

Comment: thanks for correction and link

Answer (score 0):

try `<label style="font-weight: 700;">Foo Bar</label>` or in css `label { font-weight: 700; }`
Font-Weight 400 represent a "regular" font, while 700 is a "bold" font.

I set up a little Fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/5cqdysug/

If you have a TTF/OTF file you could make a webfont out of it with http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator, afterwards you can controll the font-weight stuff of the font, for more information on this please check the link provided by @dcc http://www.maketecheasier.com/use-google-roboto-font-everywhere/

Hope this helps